# Querying not acting as expected with az-cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am currently trying to filter where a specific `tag` contains a match of a value, however the `az resource list --query ""` doesn't seem to like what I am doing.

An example of what I am executing is below:

```
az resource list \
--resource-group "${resource_group}" \
--location "${location}" \
--query "[?contains(tags.Schedule, 'NOT_SET')].name
```

As per the above you can see that there is a tag called `Schedule` on the resource, and I am trying to identify which Azure resources that have the tag value of `NOT_SET`.

This works perfectly fine when not trying to utilise the `contains` function on input data that isn't a sub-object, for example the following works perfectly well:

```
az resource list \
--resource-group "${resource_group}" \
--location "${location}" \
--query "[?contains(name, 'myvm')].name
```

I have gone through the JMESPath documentation which doesn't show the particular case I am working with here. Also a bit of a run around on google identified some possibilities such as; [Azure Citadel - CLI 2.0 JMESPATH](https://azurecitadel.github.io/guides/cli/cli-3-jmespath/), which does give an example on a different type of query

```
az vm list --show-details --output json --query "[?ends_with(storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.storageAccountType, 'LRS')]"
```

This actually works, however its on `az vm list` as opposed to `az resource list` which I am querying.

Any additional insight, or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can run the commands as expected when you add the symbol **[ ]** in your example. Correctly It should look like this:

```
az resource list \
--resource-group "${resource_group}" \
--location "${location}" \
--query "[?contains([tags.Schedule], 'NOT_SET')].name"
```

The output in my lab is as below:

[image]